# Best way to package a class for use in another app?

Tags: java, android

I've written an Android app which various abstract classes that perform useful functions. These functions could be leveraged in other apps.

I want to share a class module with another programmer, but I don't want to share the source code. I would like to share a .class file but I'm not sure how to do the following:

- Compile an Android .java file into .class
- What does the receiver of the .class file have to do to use that .class in their project? (using Eclipse environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would share it using a .jar file.  Eclipse has a wizard for exporting your classes as a jar file.

To import it into your Android project in Eclipse:
https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to create a JAR.  There's a lot of information about how to do this in Eclipse.  See [this how-to](http://bitrazor.com/content/tivo/hme/howtos/create_jar.php) for a start.  Basically, you just go to File->Export->Jar File.  For the import side, see [How to Add JARs to Project Build Paths in Eclipse (Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).

However, you should realize that it's quite easy to decompile Java classes.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the warning. I suppose I should just release open source anyways. At least now I understand my options!

Comment: I gave you +1 and accepted the other answer because you guys both posted at the same time and I had to pick one :) Great answer though - thanks again!